# can i use wcf rest service in my asp.net 3.5 web application

Tags: asp.net, wcf, rest

I heard that rest services are moved from wcf to asp.net web api frame work.

Our web application is built on vs 2010  (asp.Net 3.5) .So still i can use wcf rest services in my web application?

Please suggest some alternatives if it is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF can still be used to build RESTful services<sup>1</sup>, many services are already built with it and it's not going away. What you heard is that most of the new developments in terms of new functionality in the area by Microsoft will be made in the ASP.NET Web API framework, not in WCF. But as all the services out there can attest, WCF for building web services is still a valid alternative, if it does all you need.

---

<sup>1</sup> The official name is actually "WCF Web HTTP Services"; REST is a well-defined set of constraints which need to be implemented, which would give the service some useful properties. There are some people who argue that people should stop using the term REST for all HTTP-based, non-SOAP services.

Comment: Thanks carlosfigueira for reply.  But if i move this application from 3.5 to 4.5 in future will it effect anything ?

Comment: It shouldn't; since the .NET Framework ships with the Windows OS, I think it needs to be supported by MS by at least 10 years. So the update from 3.5 to 4.0 (or 4.5) should be smooth (i.e., non-breaking). I used to work on the WCF team (left about 2 years ago) and they had a very, very, very high bar for breaking changes - if something works on one version of the framework, it should continue so on the newer ones. I don't think this has changed.